# What are the controls for Geometry Dash while using a PS4 controller connected to a phone

Tags: ps4, controllers, geometry-dash, mobile

I am trying to connect my PS4 controller to my phone. I was able to connect it but now I want to play Geometry Dash with the controller. I tried it, but only a few things worked, pause the level, exit the level, and that's it. Now I want to know how I can jump?  And how can I play levels? I want to do this by not by tapping the screen, but by pressing buttons on the controller.

What I want to know is, what are the controls for GD on phone with a PS4 controller?

Comment: What I want to ask, what are the controls for GD on phone, with a PS4 controller?